# Number format conversion

Tags: xslt

I have an incoming value like -  `46.2` , `46.54`

I am trying to convert like  `+000004620` , `+000004654`

I am doing this below approach :

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate($amt, '.', ''), '+000000000')" />`   ( $amt is variable for that field)

With this approach it is having issue if the incoming value is something like - `46.2` ( in my case it is coming like - `+000000462`)

Can somebody help how to achieve this.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(100 * $amt, '+000000000')" />
```

Note that this assumes the amount is never negative. And that amounts should be rounded to the nearest cent, using the rounding rules defined for `format-number()` (which could be implementation-dependent).